# Multi words in filter term

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have a document with a tags field contain "john smith"
This query returns it:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "tags": "john"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this not:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "tags": "john smith"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why? How can I reach filter matches multiple words?

Comment: Hi, Did you get a chance to go through my answer

Comment: Can you share mapping of tags field.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) if I understand your requirements properly, which is you want to search for multiple values ie `john` or `smith`.

### index def

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "tags": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Index sample docs

```
{
   "tags" : "john Lay"
}

{
   "tags" : "john opster"
}

{
   "tags" : "john smith"
}
```

### Search query for `john` or `lay`

```
{
    "query" : {
        "terms" : {
            "tags" : ["john", "lay"],
            "boost" : 1.0
        }
    }
}
```

### And search result

```
"hits": [
         {
            "_index": "so_auto",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "9",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
               "model_name": "john smith"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "so_auto",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "10",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
               "model_name": "john opster"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "so_auto",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "12",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
               "model_name": "john Lay"
            }
         }
```

Comment: @Elasticsearch Ninja
You misunderstand me. My query is "john smith", and I'd like to match only documents that tags field contains "john smith"

Comment: @LayAndrás, your tag field contains exactly `john smith` ?  and can you provide mapping of your `tag` field?

Comment: @LayAndrás, could you please answer my previous question, accordingly I can modify my answer :)]

Answer (score 0):

I have create sample index with provided fields and it gave correct answer.
Mapping of the `tags` field that I have used to create index is :

```
"mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "tags": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
}
```

We are using `keyword` field since in term query you will require exact match.

I have created three documents in this index with following tags field :

```
{

            "_index": "secesindex",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "tags": "John Smith"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "secesindex",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "tags": "John Farraday"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "secesindex",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "tags": "John"
            }
        }
```

Now when I am running query as mentioned above :

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "tags": "John Smith"

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It gives exact match to the document which has tags field value equal to "John Smith".

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "secesindex",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.0,
                "_source": {
                    "tags": "John Smith"
                }
            }
]
```